# PHP - Selft class conversion

Tags: php

(Firstable: sorry for my English :D)

Can I determinate, how my objects should be converted to other types?

For example:
I have a classes:

```
<?php
    class A { 
        public $foo;
        public $bar;

        public function __construct($foo, $bar) {
            $this->foo = $foo;
            $this->bar = $bar;
        }
    }


    class B {
        public $foo;

        public function __construct($foo) {
            $this->foo = $foo;
        }
    }

    $a = new A(5, 8);

    $b = (B) $a; //conversion object with type A, to type B
?>
```

I want to have following rules:
During conversion from A to B:
 - $foo (A) should be copied to $foo (B)
 - $bar should be omitted

Can I declare a conversion method?

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you explain more?

Comment: I want to converse object (class A) to class B.
How can I do this?

Comment: Something like:
string str = 5;
int a = (int) str;
(in c++)

Comment: All you can do is to write your B constructor in a way that when the parameter is an instance of A, then it uses the A attributes to set B attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that possible? According to [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) it is only possible for certain types.

EDIT: See [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#31781)

Answer (score 0):

I think, that I found a solution:
I noticed, that in C# I can converse in this way:

```
int i = 5;
string str = i.toString();
```

so, can I do something like this?

```
class A { 

        ...
        ...

        public method toB() {
            $result = new B();
            $result->foo = $this->foo;
            return $result;
        }
    }
```